# CumulocityLongPollingTransport - canceling the long poll request because of inactivity

Tags: cumulocity

I am using the Cumulocity java agent (7.38.0) and it apparently lost communication with the server somehow and never recovered. The admin interface says:

`LAST COMMUNICATION
November 22, 2016 2:25 AM`

and last cumulo record in the the device syslog was:

`Nov 22 01:25:47 localhost root: 01:25:47.166 [CumulocityLongPollingTransport-scheduler-2] WARN  c.c.s.c.n.ConnectionHeartBeatWatcher - canceling the long poll request because of inactivity`

(there was 1 hour time diff due to some device config prob.)

process looks running anyways:

`ps -ef | grep -i c8y
root      1341  1257  0 Nov19 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh ./c8y-agent.sh
root      1342  1341  0 Nov19 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh ./c8y-agent.sh
root      1344  1342  0 Nov19 ?        00:25:39 java -cp cfg/*:lib/* -Dlogback.configurationFile=cfg/logback.xml c8y.lx.agent.Agent`

Has anyone seen this prob before?

Comment: unfortunately I continue seeing this. 4 out of 4 test devices became unreachable recently with the same symptom. (They do autonomous measurements without getting new instructions from the cumulo platform often for days.) I will try to implement some daily ping in order to avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

We had it once or twice when people were connecting to cumulocity via firewall or vpn. The result was exactly as you described: the polling gets stuck after some time, like if connections were blocked. In other words i would suspect that it’s a proxy that’s blocking the reconnect.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for the answer. The agent is running behind a normal firtzbox with default configuration. Around this time it is even very unlikely that I would have applied any change... no vpn or firewall or proxy is configured.

Comment: unfortunately I am still losing all the devices regularly due to this. These are behind 3 completely different Internet lines... André also suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453134 that some network element blocks communication but in my case I only have FritzBox / KD modem in between. Is there a way to schedule a regular "ping" operation to all devices? Something like a cron on the cumulo platform? Or could anyone post an example for this suggestion please: "Use the MQTT API and set a higher ping rate". (Ideally 1 operation to ping all devices. Not one by one.) Thanks